# Is there a version of scintilla (scilexer.dll) that includes "style"(CSS) lexing for HTML?

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting, lexer, scintilla

I'm fairly sure that *text-highlighting* (through separating the different kinds of text) is part of the scintilla lexer's  job. If it's not and is instead program specific, then please correct me.

The current version of scintilla's HTML lexer has support for script tag elements (i.e. `<script>`) and other types of embedded code, but not for stylesheet tag elements (i.e. `<style>`) such as CSS.

My friend uses Notepad++ (which uses Scintilla) for web editing and would like this feature. Before I run off and build him a custom version, I figured I'd ask if anyone else has already added this though.

Before people recommend checking the latest version of Scintilla (because Notepad++'s version is 2 years behind) for if it's got this feature already, I've built the latest version and tested it. It does not work with embedded CSS either.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to the latest version of Notepad++ (6.3.2) as it already caters for CSS syntax highlighting.